# Java design pattern - How to apply offers on product and shopping cart

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am working on a shopping cart application which will output price of cart.
I have 3 classes for this Cart, Purchase, Product

```
public class Product {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    Offer offer;
// getter setter

    public double getPrice(int quantity) {
        return offer.getPrice....
    }

}

public class Purchase {

    Product product;
    int quantity;
// getter setter

    public double getPrice() {
        return product.getPrice(quantity);
    }

}

public class Cart {

    List<Purchase> purchase = new ArrayList<Purchase>();
    Offer offer;
    Integer loyalityPoints;
//getter setter

    public double getTotal(){
        double total = 0;
        for (Purchase purchase : purchase) {
            total += purchase.getPrice();
        }

        double finalPrice = offer.getPrice(total,....;
        return finalPrice;
    }


}
```

As shown above individual product can have offer and cart can also have offer.

Initially I thought of having offer factory. 
OfferPrice can be abstract class & its child could be buyonegetoneprice, buytwogetoneprice, 50precentoffprice but then input for buyonegetoneprice will be qunatity and price and input for  50precentoffprice is only price.

This means 2 different method but implementor of OfferPrice is concerned with only one implementation.

Also how could offer on cart look like? offer on cart can be based on customer loyalityPoints or 50percentoff or something else.

How to design these offers for cart and individual product in a way that could be extensible?

Answer (score 1):

From your example you may need different Offer strategy. In my opinion the You should have all these three classes loosely coupled by using interfaces. Create OfferStrategy and subclasses like Product based offer, Price based offer etc.

This also looks like something that can benefit from Rules engine (You can dynamically change Offer for entire application without stopping the application)

Here is my suggestion for the design (Interfaces for each class, strategy to encapsulate different Offer algorithms which internally use Rules):
*Ixxx represents interface, <- represents **is a** relation

IOffer <- Offer , IProduct <- Product , IPurchase <- Purchase , IOfferStragegy <- OfferStrategy* (Different implementations with common interface method)
ICart <- Cart 
Cart **has** products and offers.

Here are the benefits/reason for doing this :

1. Assuming that the Offer and Offer implementation are going to keep changing thus needs Interfaces and ability to change at run time.
2. Cart price is determined based on offer strategy